# developer console says: "Last Merchant Sales Report n/a"

Tags: android, google-play

for some time now, my developer console overview shows a small box named "Merchant sales report" in which is written:

> Last Merchant Sales Report n/a
>   [image: screenshot]

What does that mean?

Comment: Hmm no clue. A screenshot might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a report for the sales over the last month.

As you haven't had any sales (plus haven't got any apps that could have sales) it shows N/A (Not applicable).

When you do have sales, clicking it downloads a CSV file containing details of what has happened.

The CSV has these column titles:

> Order Number,Order Charged Date,Order Charged Timestamp,Financial Status,Payout Date,Device Model,Product Title,Product ID,Currency of Sale,Item Price,Taxes Collected,Charged Amount,Merchant Currency,Estimated FX Rate,Merchant Receives,City of Buyer,State of Buyer,Postal Code of Buyer,Country of Buyer

**EDIT**

Here google have just made a Blog Post: [Merchant Sales Report](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/merchant-sales-reports-on-android.html)

Comment: thanks. this sounds like gaining a lot of data when selling apps. Can I somehow get access to these data when offering my app for free?

Comment: See on your screenshot, below the number of downloads click **statistics**

Comment: there I can only see the country, the buyer is coming from and the language he is using. More detailled information is not provided, e.g. the buyer´s city?

Comment: You won't get that, as those are details from a buyers credit card, sorry.